# Ext js Grid problem displaying date in safari

Tags: php, javascript, extjs, integration

I build grid in Ext js. In Firefox, crome Its displaying all field perfect, **but safari its display Date NaN/NaN/0NaN**

**For create i write**

```
{header: "Date", dataIndex: 'date_', renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), editor:date_edit},
```

**for edit i write**

```
var date_edit = new Ext.form.DateField({format: 'm/d/Y'});
```

**injs i write for date.**

```
{header: "Date", dataIndex: 'date_', renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'), editor:date_edit},
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed bug in Safari: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?106354-Dates-coming-as-NaN-on-Safari-only